# error: [WinError 87] El parámetro no es correcto al convertir un python a exe

Tags: python, exe

Intento hacer un ejecutable exe con este archivo setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup 
import py2exe
from math import sqrt 

setup(console=['C:\\Users\\Daniel\\Desktop\\programa python\\programa.py'])
```

El programa.py funciona perfectamente en el motor de python.
Me da el siguiente error:

```
C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\programa python>python setup.py py2exe
running py2exe

  3 missing Modules
  ------------------
? _posixshmem                         imported from multiprocessing.resource_tracker, multiprocessing.shared_memory
? readline                            imported from cmd, code, pdb
? test                                imported from multiprocessing.util
Building 'dist\programa.exe'.
error: [WinError 87] El parámetro no es correcto.

C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\programa python>
```

---

Como ya he dicho, el programa, que es una prueba, es muy sencillo y funciona bien en el motor de Python:

```
import math
print("prueba")
raiz=math.sqrt(25)
print(raiz)
```

He puesto "import math" en el setup. Es decir, importo el módulo math completo, pero sigue sin funcionar. En el tutorial de py2exe dice que hay que instalar el Microsoft Visual C runtime DLL. Nada, lo he instalado y sigue igual. También he incluido el siguiente bloque en el programa principal, sin resultado:
'' '
if **name** == '**main**':
root.mainloop()
'' '
Importando previamente la función a la que hace referencia root. Mismo mensaje de error.

Solucionado. He vuelto  instalar Python en 32 bits (no sé si anteriormente me habría instalado el de 64 sin querer). También pywin32 y pyreadline.

Comment: Por el mensaje de error, parece ser que tienes algún problema en tu código, subirlo para poder ver ese error seri¡ía bueno para responder. un saludo

Comment: Por favor, pon tu respuesta abajo, como respuesta. EN un rato puedes incluso marcarla aceptada, para que otros sepan qué deben revisar :)

Answer (score 0):

Revisa que no haya [alguien o algo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59131706/environmenterror-winerror-87-the-parameter-is-incorrect) interfiriendo con tu proceso. Antivirus o similares. Y trata de no trabajar sobre carpetas del usuario, porque Windows es un fastidio cuando cambias archivos en carpetas de usuario o del sistema.

O prueba corriéndolo en una terminal de administrador

Comment: El programa y el setup están en el escritorio. Probaré a ponerlo en C: directamente. Por otro lado, los scripts de py2exe están en una carpeta predefinida del sistema donde se instalan varios packages y esa no quiero cambiarla. También probaré a ejecutar como administrador la consola. ¡Gracias!

Comment: Tampoco funciona nada de esto